# Execute array of async functions with delay, node js

Tags: node.js, async-await

```
const filesToTranslate = await getFilesToTranslate();
await Promise.all(filesToTranslate.map(async item => {
  doExtraction(item)
}));
```

I would like to execute `doExtraction` every 30 seconds so the server don't choke.

Any smart to do that?

Comment: This will execute doExtraction() serially, every 30 seconds a single doExtraction(). Is that what you need?

Comment: @artfulbeest Yes thats correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a timeout:

```
const filesToTranslate = await getFilesToTranslate();
for (const item of filesToTranslate) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 30000));
    doExtraction(item);
}
```

Using `await` inside the loop will pause the iteration until the `Promise` has resolved.

---

If you want the first `doExtraction` to execute immediately:

```
const filesToTranslate = await getFilesToTranslate();
for (const item of filesToTranslate) {
    doExtraction(item);
    if (filesToTranslate.Slice(-1) !== item) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 30000));
    }
}
```

Comment: await won't without parent async function, In order to use await you should always have an async function.

Comment: @kamal The parent function must be async; `await` is being used for `getFilesToTranslate()`.